# Why Does Discord Say All of My Bot's Commands Require Admin Privileges to be Used?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Discord shows that my bot (written with Discord.NET) REQUIRES users to have admin even though I never require it, both in my permissions added in the Discord Developer Portal, and in my code.

Here is what users without admin see when they type "/":

[image: this]

An example of how I create a command (notice that there is zero mention of permissions):

```
[EnabledInDm(false)]
[SlashCommand("ping", "find out client latency")]
public async Task Ping()
{
    await RespondAsync(text: $" Pong! The client latency is **{Bot.Client.Latency}** ms.");
}
```

Here is what is shown on EVERY command on my Discord bot in the integrations tab found in server settings.

[image: this]

When "View" is clicked:

[image: this]

Why does only my bot do this? When I invite other bots they have no mention of requiring admin. For the record ALL commands work with a user who has admin privileges.

- I have invited other bots and zero of them had this issue.
- I have tried adding permissions requirements, and this did nothing
- I can manually add roles to users, but I should NOT have to do so (it should act like how all other bots I have invited work and not force Admin permissions on to all commands i.e. the following image:

[image: this]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of what exactly caused the issue, but changing the Discord.NET version from `3.6.1` to `3.10.0` worked.

Also, this is similar to https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/2515